# how to fix RuntimeError: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread DISCORD.PY

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, runtime-error

so, my error i get is: `((verify.darkys.wtf:3.8)) [darkehld@server196 verify.darkys.wtf]$ python main.py WARNING:discord.client:PyNaCl is not installed, voice will NOT be supported Exception in thread Thread-2: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/alt/python38/lib64/python3.8/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 95, in add_signal_handler signal.set_wakeup_fd(self._csock.fileno()) ValueError: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/alt/python38/lib64/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner self.run() File "/opt/alt/python38/lib64/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs) File "/home/darkehld/virtualenv/verify.darkys.wtf/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 701, in run loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, lambda: loop.stop()) File "/opt/alt/python38/lib64/python3.8/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 97, in add_signal_handler raise RuntimeError(str(exc)) RuntimeError: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread`

my main.py looks like this:

```
def discordbot(self):

        self.bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", help_command=None, intents=discord.Intents().all(),activity=discord.Game(name="Darkys Backup"))

        @tasks.loop(seconds = 3)
        async def myLoop():
            for i in ListToSend:
                membercount = str(len(Memberdb.GetMembers()))
                channel = discord.utils.get(self.bot.get_all_channels(), id=int(self.log_channel))
                embed = discord.Embed(title='', description="""
**✅ | Member verified**
≡ | User: <@{0}>
≡ | Ip: `{1}`
≡ | Member in db: `{2}`
""".format(i['userid'],i['ip'],membercount), color=5763719)
                await channel.send(embed=embed)

                guild = self.bot.get_guild(int(self.ServerId))
                role = get(guild.roles, name=self.role_name)
                try:
                    await get(self.bot.get_all_members(), id=int(i['userid'])).add_roles(role)
                except:
                    pass
            ListToSend.clear()
```

...

```
        myLoop.start()
        threading.Thread(target=self.bot.run,args=(self.BotToken,)).start()
```

now i think the error is because of the threading.thread line bumt idk for sure.

i tried changing self.bot.run to self.bot.start but then i get errors with never awaited.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you don't want to use a separate thread in conjunction with `async`.
Instead, just call [`self.bot.run()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.run); it'll deal with everything for you, and yes, it will block until the bot ends.

> i tried changing `self.bot.run` to `self.bot.start` but then i get errors with never awaited.

[According to the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.start) `start` is a shorthand for `login` and `connect`, and will require to be awaited.

Comment: thx, finally know how to use it and it worked